# How to get back to Ubuntu 20.04 file manager?

Tags: 22.04, filemanager

Since I have upgraded my PC from 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 a few days ago, uplading photos from browser has become a pain in the neck:

1. The file manger does not show chosen photo in the window's side.
2. It does not remember the path of the last photo's upload, so you need to give path each time.
3. The upload window does not have any UP/back navigation.

UX hardly can be any more awkward than this. It is what you get on Xfce desktop.

So I'm wondering how to get rid of this "upgrade" and come back to good old filemanager of 20.04? Any alternative solutions to overcome these shortcomings are also much appreciated.

Comment: The standard GNOME file-manager is `nautilus`, the version of which varies but matches the version of GNOME being used. Ubuntu Desktop uses GNOME, thus uses that default. You can use whichever file-manager you like though, I tend to use specific file-managers depending on what I want to accomplish, having multiple installed (*but I don't change the default; just load & use others when I prefer to*)

Comment: I'm using `Gnome Classic` right now at login and `nautilus 42.2`. What file manager do you suggest that does not have these shortcommings? And how to install it?

Comment: I can't provide suggestion sorry... I have of course `nautilus` installed, along with `pcmanfm-qt` (LXQt's FM), `thunar` (Xfce's FM), `dolphin` (KDE Plasma' FM), `caja` (MATE's FM).. & others but I don't use them as you do, thus can't say. They are just packages so you need only `apt install` but be aware they can bring in other *deps* (eg. LXQt uses Qt5, KDE needs Qt5 + KF5, other DEs maybe GTK3 like GNOME but can still use different libs etc) but my install is a multi-desktop install already & I'm aware of effects/consequences... & always weight *cost vs benefit* before I start another app.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get rid of this upgrade is to remove your current Ubuntu installation and install the older back.

It is indeed worrying how common sense workflows may break in newer versions. A file dialog should remember the last used directory, and not force the user to go back and back again to a working directory where some work resides.