# How to add image preview to nautilus Open Files window?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, photo

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04,the image preview disapeared in `Open Files` window, which is very annoying. Without a preview, how are we supposed to know which file is the photo that we are about to upload?

[image]

This happned to me in `GNOME nautilus 42.2`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get back to Ubuntu 20.04 file manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467495/how-to-get-back-to-ubuntu-20-04-file-manager)

Comment: No, it does not. That's why I asked this more specific quesiton.

Comment: You can select the **Grid View** instead of the **List View** using the four square button (`⸬`) at top right.

Comment: @FedKad I don't have this button.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405785/no-file-preview-while-opening-an-image-in-22-04

Comment: **There's no way**. There are a lot of posts of people complaining about it but nobody seems to be working on it https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/uenhr3/how_am_i_supposed_to_select_a_picture_when_i_cant/.

Comment: GNOME added it last year: https://release.gnome.org/44/ but of course LTS releases being what they are, this version won't be available in 22.04.

Comment: @muru where is it written on the page?

Comment: Quite literally the first new feature in that page is: "GNOME’s file chooser dialogs have only ever had a list view, which is great when you want to pick a file based on its name, but isn’t so good when picking files based on their thumbnails. Over the years, GNOME users have therefore repeatedly requested that a grid view be added to the file chooser.

With GNOME 44, that request has finally been answered." It even has a screenshot showing the new dialog with thumbnails visible.